# Fedora 20 Gnome 3 DE upper bar

Tags: fedora, gnome3, desktop-environment

I am a new Fedora 20 64-bit user and I used Gnome Tweak Tool to customize the appearance of the UI. However, I was not able to get the active application from the top bar. I am providing a screenshot to visualize the situation, Google Chrome is the active application and it is shown in the upper bar, I want that entry to disappear if possible since I already have a bottom bar populated with open applications. How can I do that?
[image]

Comment: I use F20 as well, but have stopped using GNOME3. You can get rid of that active icon using one of the extensions from the gnome.org site, https://extensions.gnome.org/. I cannot recall the name, so have a look, if you're still stuck I can assist further.

Comment: @slm I will try it tomorrow and let you know. So it is referred to as the active icon right?

Comment: That sounds right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell extension `TaskBar` proved useful in my case, it can be accessed via [this link](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/584/taskbar/). In order to disable the active application icon I went into the preferences of this shell extension then under the *Misc* tab I switched the slider to on next to the `Hide Default App Menu`. I do not know if this is the expected effect of this setting but I achieved the desired effect. You may wish to look at the screenshot below:

[image]